# Access class variables in functions - Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following code:

```
class MyView(View):
    var2 = Choices.objects.get(id=1)
    my_strings = ['0','1','2','3']

    @login_required
    def myfunction(self,request):

        return render(request,
              'app/submit.html',{'my_strings':my_strings, 'var2':var2})
```

I want to access "var2" and "my_string" variables and display them in the template submit.html. If I use only the function without putting it in a class, everything works fine. But inside the class it shows errors.

Can anybody tell me how to access "var2" and "my_string" class variables in "myfunction" ?

Comment: Have you done all the django tutorials? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/

Comment: Someone posted an answer but now  is deleted ? why? that's correct right ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use self. In front of class variables.

Your function names in class based views should correspond to what http method you try to use(get, post etc...)

```
@login_required
def get(self,request):

    return render(request,
          'app/submit.html',{'my_strings':self.my_strings, 'var2':self.var2})
```

Please also read:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/class-based-views/intro/

Comment: I did this but it shows an error:
__init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: stacktrace? need some more info.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write custom function to dispatch request...Django internally have the GET and POST method to do that... And also preferred way to handle login required is `method_decorator`

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator 

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MyView(View):

    string = "your string"

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'template', {'string': self.string})
```